# How to use multiple Queues in a single gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have multiple Queues and I want to use a single Gateway. I have default channel. Is there a simple way to define multiple source of Queues.

In this case "Simple" is defined as simplicity of runtime complexity than configuration.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; if you want a different channel for each method, add `<method/>` elements with the appropriate channel references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [RecipientListRouter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter):

```
<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="routingChannel">
  <int:recipient channel="queue1"/>
  <int:recipient channel="queue2"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>
```